# In PHPStorm, how can I make type hinting work when I have a superclass method that returns a different type from each subclass

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have a class that is inheriting from a superclass and where the superclass has a static `find()` method that instantiates instances of the subclass (active record pattern).

```
class ActiveRecordClass {

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function find() {
        // Code returns instance of called class
    }
}

class ModelClass extends ActiveRecordClass {

}

// returns instance of ModelClass, but PHPStorm doesn't realise
ModelClass::find($model_id);
```

At the moment, the docblock is not much good for code completion and type hinting. I can't use the superclass as a return type as the subclasses have different methods due to DB columns.

How can I indicate to PHPStorm that the superclass `find()` method returns an instance of the subclass it's called from, so that code completion works?

Comment: Use `@method` in your `ModelClass` to re-declare parent's `find()` method with the signature you require.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it:

```
class ActiveRecordClass {

    /**
     * @return static
     */
    public static function find() {
        // Code returns instance of called class
    }
}
```

It seems that `@return self` vs `@return static` works the same way that you would expect given what the keywords normally do. `@return self` did not pick up the methods available on the concrete subclass, but `@return static` make autocomplete work great.

Comment: can you show link to documentation? I didn't find 'static' at http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/types.html

Comment: @VasilVanchuk https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#keyword -- #14 at the very bottom.

Comment: would @return $this work? https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#keyword

Comment: I've been using @return static keyword in phpstorm 7 if I remember correctly but it stopped providing auto complete correctly in php storm 2016.1

Comment: Separate but related question: This works for parent classes, but it wouldn't work for factories, right? static allows for children... You'd have to explicitly write `@return ClassA | ClassB | ClassC`, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
* @var ModelClass
**/ 
$model = ModelClass::find($model_id);
```

like that   - set variable type with phpDoc

Also http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/types.html
say that you can use 'self' as type of returning value

> 13 self, the element to which this type applies is of the same Class, or
>   any of its children, as which the documented element is originally
>   contained.
>
> For example:
>
> Method C() is contained in class A. The DocBlock states that its
>   return value is of type self. As such method C() returns an instance
>   of class A. This may lead to confusing situations when inheritance is
>   involved.
>
> For example (previous example situation still applies):
>
> Class B extends Class A and does not redefine method C(). As such it
>   is possible to invoke method C() from class B. In this situation
>   ambiguity may arise as self could be interpreted as either class A or
>   B. In these cases self MUST be interpreted as being an instance of the
>   Class where the DocBlock containing the self type is written or any of
>   its child classes.
>
> In the examples above self MUST always refer to class A or B, since it
>   is defined with method C() in class A.
>
> If method C() was to be redefined in class B, including the type
>   definition in the DocBlock, then self would refer to class B or any of
>   its children.

so try

```
/**
 * @return self
 */
public static function find() {
    // Code returns instance of called class
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Sounds perfect, but doesn't seem to work with @return self. The topmost suggestion is what I have been doing so far, but it's a bit laborious and I was hoping to just define the return type :(

Comment: looks like phpDoc does not supported Late Static Binding. ( in my case it understend result as ActiveRecordClass ). So you can use another ability /**
 * @var B $b
 */
$b = B::find();