# PHPStorm type hinting subclasses of baseclass

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

With respect to this post:

[In PHPStorm, how can I make type hinting work when I have a superclass method that returns a different type from each subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26470325/178728),

this one is about an edge case in PHPStorm type hinting. 
Please try to follow along - I'll do my best to be as clear as possible:

So, I've got this base abstract class:

```
abstract class myBaseController {
    protected $_model;
    ...
}
```

which another class inherits from:

```
class myController extends myBaseController {
    $hello = 'hello';
    ...
}
```

and which is further extended by a third class:

```
class myNewController extends myController {
    public $myvar;
    $this->_model = new myModel();
    ...

    public function myFunc(){
        // !!form is underlined as: "Method 'form' not found in class"!!
        $form = $this->_model->form($new_variable); 
    }
```

Below is a sample of the myModel class:

```
class myModel extends BaseModel {
    $world = 'world';
    public function form($my_variable) {
        do_something();
    }
```

---

My true question is how to properly "phpdoc" this scenario:

**A subclass `myNewController` is using an inherited variable `_model` to assign an instance of another class `myModel` which has a unique function `form`. How should PHPStorm properly find out about `form` in `myNewController`?**

My solution so far involves documenting `myBaseController` like this:

```
abstract class myBaseController {
    /**
     * @var object
     */
     protected $_model;
    ...
}
```

However I think `@var object` is too broad (PHPStorm won't find its declaration) and my guess is that there should be a better (and more specific) way to do this.

Maybe we could instead do:

```
/**
 * @var BaseModel
 */
```

if PHPStorm had a way of looking into the subclasses for the method.

Any ideas?
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Try: ` /**
     * @var $variableName ClassName
     */`

Comment: @lolka_bolka If I do that it's going to work but then `$_model` will lock down to `ClassName`. `$_model` should be free to be assigned any of my model classes where each may have unique methods. Therefore I should -ideally- document `$_model` from within the subclass `myNewController`.

Comment: Could you please comment on the downvote?

Comment: If you want such functionality where the inheriting class returns a different type of object, you enforce a getter method instead of directly accessing member `$_model`. Basically, you stick in an `abstract public function getModel();` in the abstract class. Every class that extends it implements that method and returns a model of a certain type. You typehint in the extending class what type of object is returned. I *think* that's the only way, I don't see how PHPStorm would be able to figure out otherwise about what object type you're thinking about..

Comment: @N.B. Right. OK. It's short of a walkaround but works allright. I guess PHPStom could work out the function by looking into all of the subclasses of `BaseModel`... if instead of `@var object` I do `@var BaseModel`...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify the property type in your subclass without introducing new code, using the `@property` annotation:

```
/**
 * @property myModel $_model
 */
class myNewController extends myController
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the job!

Comment: Nice to know. Didn't know of this `@property` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Although perhaps not the best practice, this one will certainly work for you.

You can "override" the `_model` member in the subclass and document it as of BaseModel's subclass.

```
// superclass
abstract class myBaseController {
    /**
     * @var BaseModel
     */
     protected $_model;
    ...
}

// subclass
class myNewController extends myBaseController {
    /**
     * @var MyDerivedModel
     */
    protected $_model;
    ...
}
```

Comment: It does work and I would have accepted your answer if it didn't introduce any new code/restructuring. Good to know though.

Comment: It's ok. That was my best thought so far, but @fschmengler's answer is much better indeed. Live and learn! ;)

Answer (score -1):

To document the class method's return, use `return $this`; `return static` also works