# PHP type hinting in PHPDoc in derived classes

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc, type-hinting

Take a look at this code example:

```
class basetype {
    public function method() {
        return false;
    }
}

class extendtype extends basetype {
    public function methodb() {
        return true;
    }
}

class aa {
    /**
     * @var basetype
     */
    protected $membera;
}

class bb extends aa {
    public function __constructor() {
        $this->membera = new extendtype();
    }

    public function dosomething() {
        $this->membera->methodb();
    }
}
```

When edited within PHPStorm I get warning that "Method methodb not found in class basetype". I work with preexisting code base and can not alter the base classes. So what can I do in order to remove this warning?

Comment: Why are you `@var basetype` the $membera variable? Yes, $membera is a type of basetype, but that may be confusing PHPStrorm. Just remove that and see if you get the same error.

Comment: I think you are misreading the warranting. Past it form phpstorm. At the end of the day it is just a hint, if your code works it doesn't matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPStorm type hinting subclasses of baseclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863786/phpstorm-type-hinting-subclasses-of-baseclass)

Answer (score 1):

You can override `$membera` in your `class BB` and give it a new doc-block with the derived type.

```
class bb extends aa {
    /**
     * @var extendtype
     */
    protected $membera;

    public function __constructor() {
        $this->membera = new extendtype();
    }

    public function dosomething() {
        $this->membera->methodb();
    }
}
```