# What self returning type should I use if method is written in an abstract class?

Tags: php, inheritance, abstract-class

I have an abstract class with self returning set-methods and its child class:

```
abstract class AbstractFoo
{
    private $bar;

    public function setBar(string $bar): self
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
        return $this;
    }
}

class Foo extends AbstractFoo
{
}
```

I create and set variables:

```
$foo = (new Foo())->setBar('bar1');                  // No warning
$foo = (new Foo())->setBar('bar1')->setBar('bar2');  // Warning
```

This code is working, but PHPStorm hints warning because `setBar()` returns an `AbstractFoo`, not a `Foo`. How to solve the problem with this hinting?

Comment: @Blackhole, your edit is wrong. In this version there's no any warnings. Only adding "extends AbstractFoo" is correct

Comment: Oh, sorry, then. Is the new edit better? And, by the way, does this question help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470325/in-phpstorm-how-can-i-make-type-hinting-work-when-i-have-a-superclass-method-th?

Comment: Yes, seems it is the similar question, thanks